# Python looping over a data frame and adding 2 conditions within an IF to not reach the final index and increment it is returning an error

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am trying to loop over a dataframe to check whether if 3 consecutive indexes have the following condition:

```
df.loc[idx, "GDP"] > df.loc[idx+1, "GDP"] > df.loc[idx+2, "GDP"]
```

Once satisfied, it means we have recession.

On iterating over it using:

```
for idx, gdp in df.iterrows():
        if (df.loc[idx, "GDP"]>df.loc[idx+1, "GDP"]>df.loc[idx+2, "GDP"]) and (idx<=length-2):
            print(df.loc[idx, "Quarter"], df.loc[idx, "GDP"], len(df.index)-3)
```

I am adding another condition in case `idx` is at it max which 65 (we have 66 rows), to iterate only intil `idx=63` and add 2 to it at the final iteration to compare the last 3 values.

I am receiving the correct results, but at the end I am having an error saying:

'the label [66] is not in the [index]'

When I splitted the both `if` into nested ones, it worked properly:

```
for idx, gdp in df.iterrows():
        if (idx<=length-2):
            if (df.loc[idx, "GDP"]>df.loc[idx+1, "GDP"]>df.loc[idx+2, "GDP"]):
                print(df.loc[idx, "Quarter"], df.loc[idx, "GDP"], len(df.index))
```

But I need them to be at the same `if` condition.

Comment: In the code you are checking index condition after indexing dataframe. Index condition should be first like `if (idx<=length-2) and (df.loc[idx, "GDP"]>df.loc[idx+1, "GDP"]>df.loc[idx+2, "GDP"]):`......................But you should avoid loop with dataframes.

Comment: @DishinHGoyani what do you suggest? I am new to python.

Comment: See how can you use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas-series-shift)... the Given answer is good to go

Answer (score 1):

Try avoiding the loop

```
recession = (
    df.GDP.gt(df.GDP.shift(-1)) &
    df.GDP.gt(df.GDP.shift(-2))
)
```

Pandas and numpy have optimized C implementations that are more efficient than python loops.

Read more in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#iteration) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16476924/6692898)

Comment: Why should I avoid the loop over data frames?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#iteration